# Is it possible to add a specific JAR to the Clojure classpath used by the nrepl server?

Tags: clojure, classpath

I use Emacs and nrepl.el for Clojure development and I want to include a JAR file (a proprietary JDBC driver that isn't available on Leiningen/Maven) on the classpath for playing around in the REPL.

I have no intention of releasing this JAR as part of a project.  I am just writing some utility functions for my own use so I would rather not make it work with Leiningen/Maven at all and just stick with the classpath.

Is it possible to add a jar manually to the set of dependencies that `nrepl-jack-in` uses?

Comment: I think you can add this to your project.clj, but I'll wait for someone  more knowledgeable to answer this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible, but not through nrepl.el, as it offloads classpath management to Leiningen.

You can use `mvn deploy:deploy-file` to deploy the JAR file into your local Maven repository. After that just add the identifier to :dependencies in `project.clj` and Leiningen will then pick it up just fine.

If that seems like too much manual work, check out lein-localrepo plugin: https://github.com/kumarshantanu/lein-localrepo.

Note that everyone who contributes to your project will need to do this manually. See https://github.com/technomancy/leiningen/wiki/Repeatability for extended discussion on why going this way is often a bad idea and goes against the grain of Leiningen. If you're working in a team, setting up a private repository is the best solution in the long run.

Comment: the maven deploy plugin is for deploying to remote repo strictly speaking, see http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-deploy-plugin/ , you want ``mvn install:install-file`` to install in the local repo

Comment: `mvn install:install-file` (as far as I know) doesn't automatically add checksum files to the repository, but sure, you can use that as well. You will just need to add those checksums manually. See here for the original discussion: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/leiningen/yMTvQZr9Vdg/discussion

Comment: Turns out it's possible with `mvn install -DcreateChecksum=true`.